# C# String to DateTime format not recognised

Tags: c#, datetime, format

I've got the following code.

```
string date = "2022-01-17-21:00:18.661";
format = "yyyy-MM-dd-hh:mm:ss.fff";
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
timetamp = DateTime.ParseExact(date, format, provider);
```

For any reason, an exception with the message "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." is thrown all the time. Additionally, I tried to write `format = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'-'hh':'mm':'ss'.'fff";`, but it did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format string isn't correct - for the hours component - for the given the date format. `h` or `hh` converts using 12 hour format, while `HH` converts using 24 hour format.

The correct format string would be:

```
format = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss.fff"
```